# How can I show custom annotations used in my models in Swashbuckle?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

We use JetBrains annotations in our code to define the nullablity behavior of our object models. I am unable to see these by default in the Swagger UI implemented using [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v5.0.0-rc5](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) so I'm assuming these are not supported by default. Is there any way to add this feature?

FYI, I am using ASP.NET Core WebApi 3.1.

Eg:

```
public class Person {
   [NotNull]
   public Id PersonId{get; set;}

   [CanBeNull]
   public Address Address {get;set;}


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a custom schema filter like (extend it with your logic):

```
public class AssignPropertyRequiredFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            var requiredProperties = context.SystemType.GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.IsDefined(typeof(NotNullAttribute)))
                .Select(t => char.ToLowerInvariant(t.Name[0]) + t.Name.Substring(1));

            if (schema.Required == null)
            {
                schema.Required = new List<string>();
            }
            schema.Required = schema.Required.Union(requiredProperties).ToList();
        }
    }
```

then register it

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(cfg => cfg.SchemaFilter<AssignPropertyRequiredFilter>());
```

Comment: Something is amiss.

Firstly, ISchemaFilter has the following signature:

`void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context);`

Even then, it appears the [NotNull] does not seem to get captured by the IsDefined you suggested. It doesn't even show up in the CustomAttributes list. Clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: >> OpenApiSchema

Answer (score 1):

Roman Marusyk had the right answer though I want to elaborate on what I had to do to get it working in my setup.

Essentially, JetBrains annotations are hidden because of a conditional compilation flag that is not on by default

```
[Conditional("JETBRAINS_ANNOTATIONS")]
public sealed class NotNullAttribute : Attribute
```

I turned it on by adding `JETBRAINS_ANNOTATIONS` to my list of compilation symbols and started to see the attributes. Once I got that, I was able to apply the logic outline by Roman Marusyk.